# Getting the locations of facebook likes

Tags: facebook

I am curious; is it at all possible to somehow get data about the locations of likers (those who have a public location anyway) on facebook pages?

I'm merely curious for statistical reasons whether A or B is more popular in country Z, etc....

I assume its not possible without a bit of coding but any points as to what would be the way to look into creating something to trawl a likes list?

Comment: Yes, statistical reasons. Seriously, they're the best.

Comment: huh?  ..................

Answer (score 1):

There's the `page_fans_country` metric of the Page's `insights` edge, e.g.

```
/cocacola/insights/page_fans_country?period=lifetime
```

to get the lifetime likes by country for the CocaCola page. You can use this with an App Access Token like this:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/insights/page_fans_country?period=lifetime&access_token={app_access_token}
```

where `{app_access_token}` is the App Access Token you want to use.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/insights#reading

Comment: Thanks. 1: So this can only done by page owners (access token)? 2: is there anyway to break it down further, e.g. by city?

Comment: Please read the docs I linked. This metric is **public**. A further breakdown is not possible if you're not the owner of the page.